# How to convert SQL to cakephp 2.8 query to query from controller

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.8

```
SELECT * 
FROM `ads_partner_wises` 
WHERE app_code = 'XuS5II' 
AND acc_id = 89 
OR app_code = 0 
AND acc_id = 0
```

Cakephp 2.8 in not working query.

Comment: cakephp 2.8 FIND() in not working.

Comment: Mixing AND and OR's with no parenthesis is always likely to produce unexpected results. specially as `acc_id` can never be both 89 AND 0 simultaniously

Comment: @RiggsFolly that is my default manually entry acc_id = 0 and app_code = 0 in database table.

Comment: @chunaravivek Ok. But that wasn't RiggsFolly's point. Read it again.

Comment: `cakephp 2.8 FIND() in not working`...it's unclear how this is relevant to the code in your question. Show the CakePHP code and explain the specific error/problem you've got. "not working" isn't an error message or a clear problem statement - we cannot suggest any fixes based on that. P.S. See [ask] and how to create a [mre] of your issue, for more guidance. As you're new, please also take the [tour] to understand how Stackoverflow works (as you were prompted to do when you created your account). Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Finally my issues fixed cakephp 2.8 now,

```
$test_data_qry = $this->AdsPartnerWises->find('all', array('conditions' => array(
            'AND' => array(
                'OR' => array(
                    'OR' => array('AdsPartnerWises.app_code' => 0, 'AdsPartnerWises.acc_id' => 0),
                    'AdsPartnerWises.app_code' => 'XuS5II', 'AdsPartnerWises.acc_id' => 89),))));
```

this using after working now thanks.